# Sed remove multiple characters

Tags: sed

I would like to replace multiple characters

```
echo "R \e&p[%20])l(a/ce" | sed 's|%20|-|g;s|\[||g;s|]||g;s| ||g;s|#||g;s|/||g;s|)||g;s|(||g;s|&||g;s|\\||g'

Rep-lace
```

Is there another way of doing so or is this it?

Replace %20 with - and the rest with nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use

```
echo "R \e&p[%20])l(a/ce" | sed 's/%20/-/g; s/[][ #/()&\\]//g'
```

Because the character set is easier to extend that way. The thing to know is that `]` has to be the first character in the set to be recognized as part of the set rather than the closing bracket.

Depending on what exactly it is you want to do, it may be worth a thought to invert the character set instead and replace everything but a specified number of characters. For example:

```
echo "R \e&p[%20])l(a/ce" | sed 's/%20/-/g; s/[^-[:alnum:]]//g'
```

This will replace `%20` with `-` and then remove all characters except `-` and alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Thank you for the information on removing all alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

In `Bash` you can use in *Parameter Expansion* + `sed`:

```
bash$ STR="R \e&p[%20])l(a/ce"
bash$ echo "${STR/"%20"/-}" | sed -r 's/[^a-z-]//gi'
Rep-lace
```